# draw ROI in image using opencv and c++

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am new in opencv. Does anybody knows what should I write instead of  " Scalar( 0, 255, 255 )"
in gray scale images?

```
rectangle(rook_image, Point( 0, 7*w/8.0 ), Point( w, w),Scalar( 0, 255, 255 ), 1, 8, 0);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass only one argument to Scalar() like

```
rectangle(rook_image, Point( 0, 7*w/8.0 ), Point( w, w),Scalar(255), 1, 8, 0);
```